# Getting all possible list slices that include a specific item

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

I am trying to find all the list slices that includes a specific item.
Let's say I have a list `w` made of five morphemes, one of which is the stem `stem` for which I would like to find every possible slice that includes it. Here is the code I wrote for that:

```
stem = 'stm'
w = ['a', 'b', stem, 'c', 'd']
w2 = w
stem_index = w.index(stem)
stem_slice1 = w[stem_index:]
stem_slice2 = w[:stem_index + 1]
slices = []

while len(w) > 0:
    w = w[:-1] # chops the last item
    if stem in w and w not in slices:
        slices.append(w)

    w_ = w[1:] # then chops the first item
    if stem in w_ and w_ not in slices:
        slices.append(w_)

    w2 = w2[1:] # chops the first item
    if stem in w2 and w2 not in slices:
        slices.append(w2)

    w2_ = w2[:-1] # then chops the last item
    if stem in w2_ and w2_ not in slices:
        slices.append(w2_)

while len(stem_slice1) > 0:
    stem_slice1 = stem_slice1[:-1]
    if stem in stem_slice1 and stem_slice1 not in slices:
        slices.append(stem_slice1)

while len(stem_slice2) > 0:
    stem_slice2 = stem_slice2[1:]
    if stem in stem_slice2 and stem_slice2 not in slices:
        slices.append(stem_slice2)

print (slices)
```

When run, this code prints:

```
[['a', 'b', 'stm', 'c'], ['b', 'stm', 'c'], ['b', 'stm', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'stm'], ['b', 'stm'], ['stm', 'c', 'd'], ['stm', 'c'], ['stm']]
```

It seems to work fine, but I am wondering if there is a more Pythonic way to do the same.

Comment: Could there be multiple instances of stem, any of which would mean you want the subslice?

Comment: I am working from the assumption that stem has already been designated as stem, so there is going to be only one stem.

Comment: make slices a set, and then get rid of all of the "not in" clauses.

Comment: Sets do not take lists. I would get the error: unhashable type: 'list'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just getting the Cartesian product of all valid start and end indices should do it. In other words, two `for` loops are sufficient.

```
stem = 'stm'
w = ['a', 'b', stem, 'c', 'd']
idx = w.index(stem)
slices = []
for start in range(idx+1):
    for end in range(idx+1, len(w)+1):
        slices.append(w[start:end])
print(slices)
```

Result:

```
[['a', 'b', 'stm'], ['a', 'b', 'stm', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'stm', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'stm'], ['b', 'stm', 'c'], ['b', 'stm', 'c', 'd'], ['stm'], ['stm', 'c'], ['stm', 'c', 'd']]
```

Comment: Thank you Kevin. That certainly is more economical ;)

Comment: Alternatively, as a list comprehension: slices = [w[start:end] for start in range(idx+1) for end in range(idx+1, len(w)+1)]